# Install twitter module in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

How to install twitter module on ubuntu 16.04? There are 3 python versions running on the server. I need to install under the python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

```
python2.7 -m pip install <package>
```

Or you can use `virtualenv` to isolate the python develop environment between projects.

Answer (score 0):

sudo python2.7 -m  pip install python-twitter should install the correct twitter module on Ubuntu 
Run this in terminal